# On MySQL command line client how to stop showing result rows in the middle

Tags: mysql, database

I have entered query whose result is lots of rows and it's taking so long to display all of them how to stop displaying them while result log is still printing on the screen.

Ctrl + c does not work.

Comment: CTRL +C should work, but it may take some time to empty the buffer, which makes it look like the CTRL+C didnt work

Comment: You can use ctrl + z, but you have to re - login

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keyboard shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> to stop the query execution.